# QPSK Mod and Demod

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have implemented the attached flow graph but I am unable to receive the same data/text via file.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oCMK.png)

I am sending '0011' data via .txt file but receiving '      ' garbage data in received text file

Where is the problem in flow graph?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP repeatedly asks how to build functioning software from components that are declared obsolete and broken; this was pointed out to OP [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506491/qpsk-transmission-and-reception-in-gnuradio#comment99601407_56506491).

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot PSK Mod is a deprecated block too.